# Do people need to have their PhDs at Harvard to get tenure at MIT (and vice versa) in STEM fields?

Tags: phd, job-search, job, tenure-track

My friends and I were just discussing about this question: do people need to have their PhDs at Harvard to get tenure at MIT (and vice versa) in STEM fields?  I know theoretically, the answer is supposed to be *"No"*, and *"It depends on many other factors"*. But I just skimmed through MIT's Biology and Harvard's Biophysics department; it appears that those two giants only want to marry each other.

I wonder if there are are any detailed statistics of where faculty from H&M did their PhD and postdoc.

Comment: I don't know much about the departments you mention, but I see no evidence at all for this (and in mathematics it's certainly false).  I just looked at the first ten faculty members in the MIT biology department, alphabetically.  One assistant professor, two associate professors, and one adjunct professor (deputy director of the Broad Institute), and the rest were full professors (one emeritus).  Three were Stanford Ph.D.s, two Berkeley, two Harvard, and one each from UMass, Vienna, and Wisconsin.  This isn't a good enough sample to answer your question definitively, but it's not 100% Harvard.

Comment: +1 for asking for interesting statistical data; -1 for the question written in an argumentative way. Not upvoting for now, I encourage you to edit it to a more neutral tone.

Comment: This is probably true to some extent, but for good reasons. Harvard & MIT are located on the same street in the same town, so being a PhD student or post-doc at one more or less entails being the same at the other (speaking from personal experience). The hiring department at either H or M will then probably know the applicant personally, and they have most likely worked together. That always increases the chance of being hired.

Comment: The answer certainly is "no".  This question suffers from two misapprehensions.  First, it is not at all true that Harvard and MIT are unambiguously the top universities for STEM fields.  In my own discipline of mathematics, they are among the top, but are essentially tied with Princeton, Chicago, Berkeley, and Stanford; similar things are true in other disciplines. (continued)

Comment: Secondly, where you got your PhD probably plays *less* of a role in hiring decisions at top places like Harvard and MIT than at lesser institutions.  The kinds of people who sit on hiring committees at those kinds of places are not at all impressed by a fancy degree -- what matters is the work you have done.  This is especially true since they typically do most of their hiring at the senior level.  The majority of their faculty certainly have degrees from top places, but you shouldn't confuse correlation with causation...

Comment: Even if you find x% of faculty at MIT/Harvard, you have to look at the ratio of other large (or famous) schools doing similar things.  From how I read your question, it sounds as if you are picking out Harvard/MIT as an anomaly since you dont ask "do schools only hire from other schools in the area" or "do top schools only hire from other top schools", so you consider a look at Oxford/Cambridge as well.

Comment: _where you got your PhD probably plays less of a role in hiring decisions at top places like Harvard and MIT than at lesser institutions_ — [citation needed]

Answer (score 1):

I have never sat on a tenure case at either Harvard or MIT, so my answer is purely conjecture. While it is possible the first thing the tenure committee does is look at where the PhD is from and throws out everyone not from Harvard/MIT, that seems very unlikely. Tenure decisions are about teaching, service, and research. At the point of tenure decisions, the school your PhD is from is essentially meaningless although there may be some correlation between research productivity and where your PhD is from any longer term causative effects are probably pretty limited.

Where the PhD is from plays some role on initial hiring at all universities and if you don't have a TT position it is much harder to get tenure. Additionally, where you work probably has some causative effect on research productivity giving Harvard and MIT PhDs additional advantages (or at least preventing disadvantages). Therefore it is not surprising that lots of tenured faculty have PhDs from Harvard and MIT.

Comment: FYI: the Harvard math department has only one rank for tenure-track faculty: professor [i.e., full professor with tenure].  They sometimes hire people who become very young full professors, but most of their hires were tenure track or tenured elsewhere.  Though I don't know for a fact that "Tenure decisions are about teaching, service, and research." is inaccurate, I strongly suspect this is not the case nor even claimed to be the case.  It sure looks like they go after whoever they think is absolutely the best research mathematician they can get.

Comment: (They actually have a separate position "Professor of the Practice of Mathematics"!)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I didn't mean to imply the three were equally ranked. I wasn't aware of how Maths works at Harvard, I think that structure is not the norm.

Comment: That structure is definitely not the norm: it would only be relevant in a question which is specific to STEM departments at Harvard and MIT.  :) Part of the point of my comment is that the tenure decision is synonymous with the hiring decision, so they are not evaluating candidates on their teaching and research at the given department *at all*.  My honest guess is that teaching and service (anywhere) is not evaluated in the slightest when it comes to these hiring decisions.  It would be understandable if an expensive private university would not say this so baldly, but even so...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark yes it is relevant, but there are a lot of departments in STEM fields that have more traditional hiring and tenure processes at Harvard and MIT.

Comment: I agree with you.